# Reading files in Python 3.5 which have been generated in Python 2.7

Tags: python, multiple-versions

I have run some scritp in Python 2.7 which generated a file, and when I tried to open it I found the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 2623: ordinal not in range(128)

Any clue on how to open it in Python 3.5?

Comment: Use the correct encoding when opening the file. UTF8 is a good first guess.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you are using to generate that error here for us to see exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is in `utf-8` (probably). The ASCII codec can't decode unicode text.

You should use the proper codec. The `file.read()` function returns a bytes-like object. You can turn that into a string like so:

```
contents = str(file.read(), 'utf-8')
```

Comment: or you could specify the encoding when opening the file

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the encoding when opening the file:

```
 with open(myfile, encoding='utf-8) as f:
     pass
```